# How to override the 'as_json' or 'to_json' method in order to 'respond_to' without including specified information?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to override (possibly in the model file) the `as_json` or `to_json` method in order to `respond_to` an HTTP request without including some information.

In my Account *model* I have

```
def as_json(options = {})
  super(
    :except => [
      :password
    ]
  )
end
```

In my controller I have

```
format.json {
  render :json => @account, :status => 200
}
```

When I make a request, for example, to `/account/1.json` I have back also the password attributes that, for security reasons, I don't want.

So, **how can I prevent to include specified information?**

---

I can do this and it works

```
format.json {
  render :json => @account.to_json(:except => [:password]), :status => 200
}
```

but it I need to *refactor*.

Comment: my following solutions are working for me without refactoring. Aren't they working in your environment?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If it is only in one action you can try:

```
format.json { render :json => @account, :except => :password }
```

if you need it for more than one action than the override would be better:

```
# Exclude password info from json output.
def to_json(options={})
  options[:except] ||= :password
  super
end
```

the same is good for as_json

```
# Exclude password info from json output.
def as_json(options={})
  options[:except] ||= :password
  super
end
```

Comment: In order to work, I MUST use 'render :json => @account.to_json' instead of 'render :json => @account'. I think there is some way to do that without include '.to_json'...

Comment: in rails 3 if you override the as_json method in the model and then put format.json { render :json => @account } in the controller it works without calling to_json

Comment: Does it work if you override "serializable_hash" instead of "as_json"?

Comment: This works. I added the slightly different syntax for excluding multiple attributes.

Comment: Maybe nice to know: It is sufficient to just write `super`, as it automatically takes the same arguments the parent method has, unless you specify them yourself.

Comment: It would be better to use `options[:except] = Array(options[:except]) | [:password]` if you wanted to guarantee that the `:password` could never be sent as json.

Comment: @Ryan McGeary: Actually, the syntax `options[:except] ||= :password` seems strange to me as well. It would be equivalent to `options[:except]` if this term is truthy, to `:password` otherwise. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to override **as_json** methods in your model as following:

```
def as_json options={}
   super(
     include: {ADD THE RELATIONS YOU WANT TO INCLUDE}).merge({YOU CAN MERGE EXTRA PARAMETER HERE})
end
```

You could use **only** (which means that the only parameters that you've listed will be return) or use **except** (which means return all parameters except the listed ones).